# Regex comma as optional character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex that I made:

```
/\$([A-Za-z0-9\-\_ ]+)(\,?)/gi
```

I need to convert the following senteces:

```
$a, $b, $c, $hi = "", $na
```

Into this:

```
$a = NULL, $b = NULL, $c = NULL, $hi = "", $na = NULL
```

But I get this instead of the example above:

```
$a = NULL, $b = NULL, $c = NULL, $hi = "", $na
```

I'm using this to replace the values:

```
$$$1 = NULL$2
```

As you can see, if there isn't a comma, it won't work.

Hope you guys can help me.

**Update:** I just need to ignore it if it has "=" and a value:
For example, I have to convert this:

```
$a, $a, $a
$a, $a = '', $a
$a
$a,
$a = ''
$a = '',
$a = '', $a
```

Into this

```
$a = NULL, $a = NULL, $a = NULL
$a = NULL, $a = '', $a = NULL
$a = NULL
$a = NULL,
$a = ''
$a = '',
$a = '', $a = NULL
```

The '' can be also NULL, "" and integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\$([\w -]+)(?!\w|,?\s*=)(,?)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CQMhHU/2).

Note that `[A-Za-z0-9_]` = `\w`, thus the regex pattern can be shortened as shown above.

The `(?!\w|,?\s*=)` part is the main difference here: it makes sure there is no word char or an optional `,` followed with 0+ whitespaces and then `=` immediately after matching the Group 1 pattern, `[\w -]+`.

See the JS demo:

```js
const texts = ['$a, $a, $a', "$a, $a = '', $a", '$a', '$a,', "$a = ''", "$a = '',", "$a = '', $a", '$a, $b, $c, $hi = "", $na'];
const regex = /\$([\w -]+)(?!\w|,?\s*=)(,?)/g;
for (let s of texts) {
  console.log("`" + s + "` => `" + s.replace(regex, '$1 = NULL$2') + "`")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2

Actually you can use my original regexp, if you [edit it](https://regex101.com/r/jE121F/1) using the proper flags:

```
/(?<=\$[A-Za-z0-9\-\_ ]+)(?=(?:,|$))/gmi
```

the `m` flag here is telling `$` to match not only the absolute end of the input string (which is the EOL of the last line), but also the end of each line, which I could match with `\n` in the previous update, where I did not use the `m` flag. (The `^` metacharacter has a similar treatment.)

### Update

Since after a while you came up with the news (that I should have expected, actually, so it's my fault) that the input file is multiline you need the following variation, which looks ahead for one of three possible things, `,`  and `$`, as in my original answer, as well as a `\n` which is an EOL, for all the lines but the last:

```
/(?<=\$[A-Za-z0-9\-\_ ]+)(?=(?:,|\n|$))/gi
```

### Original answer

You can use the following regex to detect the positions where you want to insert `= NULL`:

```
/(?<=\$[A-Za-z0-9\-\_ ]+)(?=(?:,|$))/gi
```

As I have used a lookbehind and a lookahead to find the position, the whole regex actually matches no text, but just a position, so you don't need to refer to anything in the substitution, which only needs to be `= NULL`. You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/CGb46H/1).

More in detail

- `(?<=regex)` matches the position (a zero-length match) at the end of the text matched by `regex`, so in the specific example it matches just after `$a`, `$b`, ...
- `(?=regex)` matches at the position at the beginning of the text matched by `regex`, so in the specific example it matches just before `,` or `$` (EOL), which are the two alternatives separated by `|`.
- `(?:…)` is just a non-capturing version of `(…)`.

Comment: It works well in your example, but in my case, it didn't work

Comment: @JhonCartes I've used your example, not mine. What happens in "your case"?

Comment: @JhonCartes update your question with the details needed to understand what's going on (error included).

Comment: Well, after a little research I ended with this regex: `\$([A-Za-z0-9\-\_ ]+)(\,?)(?!.*(?:=))`. It's working so far with one but if there is more and a "=" character, it doesn't work..

Comment: @JhonCartes, that regex is nonsensical. The negative lookahead matches at every and only position after the last `=` on the line. So it the whole regex will not match before the only `=` which is in your line. So it will not match the varius`$a`, `$b`, and so on. Furthermore, `(\,?)` is simply the same as `(,?)`, since `,` is not special, and thus it needs not be escaped.

Comment: You're right, that's what is happening: https://regex101.com/r/MBoQgB/1.
I made this little change and it's working now but same as before, it doesn't ignore the = character: `\$([A-Za-z0-9\-\_ ]+)(,?)(?!(?:=))`

Comment: Have you at least tried reading **and understanding** my answer? Besides, give a look at the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60469413/5825294) which tries to read your mind. Maybe that is an answer for you. Or you can take it as a chance to update **your question**. Also, _it works but_ just means _it doesn't work_, so stop trying attempts randomly, and put some effort into understanding.

Comment: I've read your answer and understood it! I tried your code and it works but I still have some troubles on it. I updated my question for more further details.

Comment: You know what the `g` flag at the end of the regex is?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this "global" flag because I'm not replacing a single line, I need to replace a lot of lines, like on my example

Comment: I tried your updated regex expression and seems it works this time! But not in my code, it still colds the window

Comment: @JhonCartes, I've update the answer further, to explain the original reason for the misbehavior that you observed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the desired result for the seven-line example string given in the question is just a literal, you don't need any code; just write it down. I suspect, however, that that is just an example of a broader, unstated question. How are we to guess what that question is from a single example? I will make a guess, but it's only a guess. You need to edit your question to state the question for which you have given an example. My guess follows.

> *Substrings to be modified* begin with a dollar sign followed by one or more lower case letters followed by a comma or the end of a line in the string.
>
> I wish to replace each substring to be modified, `"$xx"` with `"$xx = NULL"`, where `"xx"` denotes any string of one or more lowercase letters.

Substrings to be modified can be identified with the regex

```
/\$[a-z]+(?=,|$)/
```

where `(?=,|$)` is a positive lookahead that requires the match to be followed by a comma or the end of a line (`$`) in the string.

Notice how this regex follows easily from a precise statement of the question.

I don't know Javascript, but in Ruby the substitution could be done as follows. If `str` is a given (possibly multi-line) string, the desired string can be obtained as follows:

```
str.gsub(/\$[a-z]+(?=,|$)/) { |s| "#{s} = NULL" }
```

I confirmed this produces the desired result for the seven-line example string in the question.

I assume this can be translated to Javascript quite easily.

Comment: It's close to what I need! I updated my question with more details! I don't need to escape those characters since I'm doing this from a non-defined value.

Comment: I changed my answer to conform with the change to your question. All that was needed was changing `\z` (end-of-string anchor) in the regex to `$` (end-of-line anchor). I don't know what you mean by not having to escape characters. `\$` is needed to indicate that `$` is a regular character and not an end-of-line anchor and `\z` (which I've now removed) is the end-of-string anchor. Those are the only characters I escaped.